Squid returning Invalid URL
I have a squid instance running together with a wireguard tunnel. Client traffic is proxied through the wireguard tunnel:
Client -> (gateway wireguard) -> (wireguard + squid)
The gateway wireguard has iptables rules to DNAT to the (wireguard + squid) instance:
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -i wg+ -j DNAT --to 10.13.13.3:4128
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -i wg+ -j DNAT --to 10.13.13.3:4128

When I request a non HTTPS website, I am faced with an invalid url, and the access.log shows an incomplete URL:
1714043450.064      0 10.13.13.1 NONE_NONE/400 2151 - /connect - HIER_NONE/- text/html
Anyone know what's going on here?
I have a simple squid proxy config:
acl all src 0.0.0.0/0
http_access allow all
acl step1 at_step SslBump1

ssl_bump peek step1
ssl_bump bump all

debug_options ALL,1

sslcrtd_program /usr/lib/squid/security_file_certgen -s /var/spool/squid/ssl_db -M 4MB

http_port 3128
http_port 4128 ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB cert=/ssl/squid.pem

http_port 3129 intercept
http_port 4129 intercept ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB cert=/ssl/squid.pem


I have just realised that the intercept was on 3129 and 4129, if I move it to 3128 and 4128, I see an access denied Access control configuration prevents your request from being allowed at this time., however, unsure what could be causing this?
1714044516.469      0 10.13.13.3 TCP_MISS/403 2505 GET http://suconfig.apple.com/resource/registration/v1/denylist.plist - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1714044516.469      0 10.13.13.1 TCP_MISS/403 2594 GET http://suconfig.apple.com/resource/registration/v1/denylist.plist - ORIGINAL_DST/10.13.13.3 text/html

Another edit, having changed that, I see why I'm getting an access denied: there is a forwarding loop: cache.log says WARNING: Forwarding loop detected for.
I suspect that's because the WG peer config has AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0. That breaks things
